# Google Maps is very slow

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am trying to use Google Maps Api 3. I have almost 1300 points to show as markers. When I want to place these markers on map, it takes more than 10 seconds also zooming in and zooming out becomes really very hard. Even, after a some point, browser says there is no enough memory. I tried to use markerclusterer as adviced [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/marker-clustering) but the result is same.

What can be the problem and how can I make this process faster?

Answer (score 0):

MarkerClusterer is a different way to display markers on a map, and you could have a smoother navigation but you will not solve the performance problem as it's a client-side clustering (The browser have to load the whole data).

To display more than 1000 markers, you need to implement a server-side mapping technology. I've wrote an article that describe how we manage big data in our product: [Display a lot of Markers on top of Google Maps](https://blog.woosmap.com/tutorials/big-data-woosmap/).

If you consider to develop a Server-Side mapping component, I highly recommend you to take a look at [Mapnik](http://mapnik.org/)